# Haskell have a function accept an unknown number of argument as parameter

Tags: haskell, types

I need my function to called like so:
`myFunc 1 5 4 3 6 2 7 8 9 5 1 3`
or
`myFunc 2 6 4`

How do write my types so it accepts an unknown number of parameters and put them in a list ?
I want to do something like this:

```
myFunc :: Int -> IO ()  -- I don't know what type to put replace Int with 
myFunc a = 
    return a
```

`myFunc 1 2 5 4 8`
should return
`[1,2,5,4,8]`

Comment: myFunc doesn't compile as is. It would compile with type `() -> IO ()` but it would still not do what you are asking. On the other hand `1 : 2 : 5 : 4 : 8 : []` is a series of function applications that would achieve what you are asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functions that can accept an “unknown number of arguments” are called [variadic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function). Haskell doesn't support variadic functions, but it has a sufficiently flexible type system to be able to fake them.

This is known as “the [printf](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Text-Printf.html#v:printf) trick” and widely considered to be an awkward hack. Think twice whether you really want this – it is *not* idiomatic Haskell, it may lead to weird error messages, and there are plenty of alternative approaches that would probably work as well or better for you.

That out of the way, here's how to do it:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class MyFuncType a where
  myFuncAcc :: [Int] -> a

instance a ~ () => MyFuncType (IO a) where
  myFuncAcc = print
instance (MyFuncType a, c ~ Int) => MyFuncType (c -> a) where
  myFuncAcc l h = myFuncAcc $ h:l

myFunc :: MyFuncType a => a
myFunc = myFuncAcc []

main :: IO ()
main = myFunc 1 2 5 4 8
```

Comment: Do you know how I could have myFunc as main, so when it is compiled into a binary I can do `./binaryName 1 2 5 4 8` and it would return `[1,2,5,4,8]`  ?

Comment: That's a completely different question from the one you were asking. (And unlike what you were asking, variadic _command-line arguments_ are actually a sensible thing to want.) Make it a new question.

Comment: Yes I know, I got around the problem using getArgs but your answer will still be really useful to me later